# SSH goes inactive

Tags: ssh

I'm using SSH to connect to my server. Often my connection becames inactive after some time: 10 minutes, 5 minutes or even sometimes in 10 seconds. And it return to live after waiting (3-5 minutes)

What are the reasons of this behavior and how can I beat it?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to resolve this:

On the server, login as root and edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add the line:

ClientAliveInterval 60

The other way, and easier and safer way is for your desktop machine to send those keep alive messages. As root on your desktop (or client) machine, edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config and add the line:

ServerAliveInterval 60

source:  http://ocaoimh.ie/how-to-fix-ssh-timeout-problems/

Comment: cool. I'll try it now